# how do I use imageresizer ater installing from nuget? namespace is not recognized

Tags: .net, imageresizer

I must be missing something obvious here.

I read many answers on SO and scoured the http://imageresizing.net/ website.

I don't want to use urls with parameters for dynamic image resizing. I want to resize images on uploads and ave the resized image on disk.

I successfully installed the nu get package.

I try to include the ImageResizer namespace in my code but its not being recognized.

I can just throw the dlls in my bin folder and add reference to them, but It seems like after installing with nu get the project should be set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have verified that your project includes ImageResizer under the References section, then you may have the .NET Client Profile selected. ([More info on this can be found in our troubleshooting guide](http://imageresizing.net/docs/troubleshoot)).

If you do not see ImageResizer under your project references, the NuGet package did *not* install properly (or you installed the wrong NuGet package).

It would be helpful to let us know what versions of .NET,  Visual Studio, and NuGet itself you are using.